# Testing filenames with regexp and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this:

```
   if (data.match(/([^\/\\]+ )\.(txt|doc)$/i) )
   return {filename: RegExp.$1, ext: RegExp.$2};
```

to only allow (when true) file .ext's that are listed. Which, for the above is txt and doc. This works well until it comes accross a filename that is just an extension Such as .DS_store. If e.g., .DS_store is encountered it stops testing. How can the statement be modified to gracefully reject filenames that only consists of the ext, while continuing to process other filenames?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `it stops testing`? it will not match the regexp, but what do you want? Explain, please, in details what do you want to change here http://jsfiddle.net/B46yq/

Comment: Here is the issue in action: http://jsfiddle.net/B46yq/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (will not match ".doc", nor "  .doc", but will parse: 'myfile/Regular name.doc'):

```
data.match(/(?=([\s]*))\1([^\/\\]+)\.(txt|doc)$/i)
```

(you gobble up leading spaces, but your situation is complicated by the fact that spaces are valid in the name. But since you can't use [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), you [mimic this behavior](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-atomic-groups) with a positive look-ahead zero-width assertion that includes zero, then a back-reference to that.)

Comment: Thanks, works great! Anyone who wants to see/use it: http://jsfiddle.net/B46yq/22/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.If I understood your question correctly...

```
var m = data.split('.')[data.split('.').length-1];
return (m == "doc" || m == "txt") ? true : false;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Ztp/1/) is the working fiddle.